# Author XSD to allow extensible element

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I want to author an XSD to validate against XML files. An example of the XML file may look like this:

```
<person>
    <fullname>John Doe</fullname>
    <age>25</age>
    <gender>male</gender>
</person>
```

One of the requirement is that the `<person>` tag is extensible, meaning that besides the 3 required child elements above, it can contain arbitrary elements with any names. So this document would be valid when validated by the XSD.

```
 <person>
    <fullname>John Doe</fullname>
    <age>25</age>
    <gender>male</gender>
    <address>USA</address>
    <profession>worker</profession>
</person>
```

I read about the `<xs:any />` element, but XSD doesn't allow me to put `<xs:any />` inside a `<xs:all />` element. I want the `<fullname>`, `<gender>` and `<age>` elements to be required, and each of them must appear exactly one. Other than that, there can be zero or many optional elements.

Is it possible to achieve this with the supported XSD rules?

Comment: I don't think it's possible with `<all>`, because only `<complexType>` can contain `<all>`, and `<all>` can't contain any other group. If it's really only 3 fields, though, you could explicitly state each order (being careful that no two choices have the same prefix, because of UPA). i.e.: `a(bc|cb) | b(ac|ca) | c(ab|ba)`.

Answer (score 0):

Combining xs:all and xs:any can create content that is ambiguous, which is why its not allowed. But you can do this if the content is contained within a xs:sequence.

*Note : Ensure the namespace and processContent attributes on the xs:any are set correctly for your requirements.*

Their is much better support for this kind of extensiblity in XSD 1.1 using the [xs:openContent](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/Reference/XmlStudio/XsdEditorNotation_OpenContent.html) tag, however support for XSD 1.1. is still limited.

[image]

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid XML 2016 Developer Bundle Edition 14.1.3.6618 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="person">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="fullname" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="age" type="xs:int" />
                <xs:element name="gender">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:enumeration value="male" />
                            <xs:enumeration value="female" />
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:any namespace="##any" processContents="skip" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```